# I can't insert values into sqlite database using Swift 4

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am trying to insert  a new user to the database. However, I get the following error:

> failure inserting user: SQL logic error or missing database

Here is the code to insert the user:

```
while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        let email = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0))
        let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
        let age = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2)
        let gender = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))

        userList.append(User(age: Int(age), name: name, email: email, gender: gender))
        print("user saved successfully")
    }
```

Name, age, email and gender are input to text fields.

Comment: I don't even know what userList.append() is.

Comment: userList() is a variable representing the list of users.I have also created a class User with the mentioned fields

Comment: When you have an issue with an error it is always helpful to us if you actually show that error in your question.  We can always guess something useless to you but that is just as ineffective.

Comment: failure inserting user: SQL logic error or missing database .This is the error

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) to manage your SQLite database. The framework is easy to use and provides a nice interface for efficient database usage. To set the database up with a SQLite file, use the following code:

```
let dataStack: DataStack = {
    let dataStack = DataStack(xcodeModelName: "ModelName")
    do {
        try dataStack.addStorageAndWait(SQLiteStore(fileURL: storagePathUrl, configuration: "Default", localStorageOptions: .
            recreateStoreOnModelMismatch))
    } catch let error {
        print("Cannot set up database storage: \(error)")
    }
    return dataStack
}()
```

You can then add a new object with

```
dataStack.perform(asynchronous: { transaction in
    let user = transaction.create(Into<User>())
    user.email = "user@test.com"
    user.name = "test"
    user.age = 18
    user.gender = "m"
}, completion: { _ in })
```

And read your object with

```
dataStack.perform(asynchronous: { transaction in
    if let user = transaction.fetchOne(From<User>(), Where("name", isEqualTo: name)) {
        userList.append(user)
    }
}, completion: { _ in })
```

Comment: With Swift 4, it gives the following errors:Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'DynamicObject'.  ,and.                    Use of unresolved identifier 'storagePathUrl'